# Confidence band for mean of means

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, prediction-interval, mathematical-statistics, philosophical

This is sort of a stats theory question, and I can't really convince myself of the correct way to view things:

In normal regression, the confidence band (or interval) gives the bounds on the mean, whereas the prediction interval gives the bounds on an individual value.

But in lots of cases, what are actually being regressed are mean data. So, for example, modeling state-wide unemployment rate based on mean education. In this setting, an 'individual value' is, in fact, already a mean. So it would seem that when regressing the mean of means, the prediction interval is really indicative of the bounds on the mean, whereas the confidence interval is sort of a useless measure of the confidence on the mean of means.

Am I just overthinking this? Does anyone have any good links or references to a discussion of this topic?